# SQL Server 2005 history tables using triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table and want to insert the current values of records that are being updated or deleted.

I tried to create a trigger on before update and on before delete but SQL Server 2005 doesn't like the before word.

How do I get this to work?

I want the trigger to take the current record and copy it to a history table that is a mirror of the base table with the two added fields of `dateBackedUp` (that takes a getDate()) and a field called `action` (that takes the action 'updated' or deleted')

please help

Comment: Please post the code that you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a concept of `BEFORE INSERT` or `BEFORE DELETE`. These kind of audit operations really don't need to be executed before the action, most of the time - so just use the `AFTER INSERT` and `AFTER UPDATE` triggers that you already have.

> using the deleted table works as it
>   gives me the data that will be
>   updated. the inserted table provides
>   the new values... not the ones i want
>   to log.

When you do an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, the `Inserted` pseudo-table contains the new values - and the `Deleted` table contains the old values. So for the `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, you can access both pseudo tables and get both the old and the new values.

The `AFTER INSERT` trigger only has access to `Inserted` pseudo table which contains the values that were inserted.

The `AFTER DELETE` trigger only has access to the `Deleted` pseudo table which contains the values of the rows that were deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `before` keyword. You can create a trigger as normal and then select from the `deleted` table which gets created when a trigger is..er...triggered.

eg

```
create trigger Audit
on tblCustomers
after update, delete

insert into tblAudit
select * from deleted;
```

(untested as I don't have a SQL Server here, but if doesn't work then the BOL entry for `Create Trigger` should tell you about the `deleted` table)

Answer (score 0):

```
create TRIGGER [update_Project] ON Project
FOR UPDATE
AS
INSERT project_history 
SELECT * FROM deleted
```

using the deleted table works as it gives me the data that will be updated. the inserted table provides the new values... not the ones i want to log.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Plus: you should **update** your original question by editing it, rather than adding a "dummy" answer yourself......